# How do I resize a PDF?

Tags: python, pdf, image-resizing

I have 100 pdf files in a folder in A0 format I'd like to scale them to A3.
I have tried various methods but none of them worked. My goal is to create a script (preferably in python) to scale all the files in A3.

I tried to use PIL but my version of python doesn't support it.

Comment: So which Python libraries have you tried and why did your attempts fail? Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

you can write commands on windows command processor

to do these functions :

-Merge PDF files together, or split them apart

-Encrypt and decrypt

-Scale, crop and rotate pages

-Read and set document info and metadata

-Copy, add or remove bookmarks

-Stamp logos, text, dates, page numbers

-Add or remove attachments

-Losslessly compress PDF files

it can work also in different OS such as  / MAC / Ubunto / Linux

scale command example :

cpdf -scale-to-fit a3portrait in.pdf -o out.pdf

using this tool Coherent PDF Command Line Tools  , you may download it from here [click here to open link](http://community.coherentpdf.com/)

you can as well use python script to execute the code for you on the command processor / terminals .

hope my post helped you , good luck

Comment: Thanks. I downloaded it and launched, when I use command processor I get 'command" is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

Comment: its working bro  , i think you are missing the way of using it  , when you download the tool , extract it on C:\mypdffiles\ 
navigate to windows path ( assuming you are using windows) by typing cd C:\mypdffiles\cpdf-binaries-master\windows

you will find in there the cpdf.exe tool , so within the same folder , place your pdf file and use the command from the same path , for example after navigating to the path above 
put in.pdf file within same folder and run cpdf in.pdf 1-3,12-end -o out.pdf

you cannot use the tool until you copy it on folder of where you are going to run the command

Comment: there is manual documents too please read them for better understanding on the same folder @Azerty

Comment: by the way , implementing it the way it works now makes it more easier to be controlled with other languages such as python for example as you can integrate it within your program code and use any where along when you type the commands

Answer (score -1):

You could try the linux `pdftk` program (although it might even be available on Windows, i am not sure). Once installed, you can use the command below to convert an A0 pdf to an A3 pdf

```
convert -page a0 infile.pdf -page a3 outfile.pdf
```

Comment: I think this answer has value